# ./waf configure error pycairo

Tags: python, cairo

I try to install pycairo both on Ubuntu and Debian.
When I use ./waf configure, it comes to this error.

```
  ./options()
Setting top to                           : /home/nathenqian/Documents/py2cairo
Setting out to                           : /home/nathenqian/Documents/py2cairo/build_directory
  ./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok
Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 6, 'final', 0)
Checking for library python2.7           : yes
Checking for program python2.7-config    : /usr/bin/python2.7-config
command ['/usr/bin/python', '/usr/bin/python2.7-config', '--includes'] returned 1
```

What's the problem? I also try this with same result. `./waf configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64`

Comment: Have you python-dev installed?